# difference between udid and client_identification_sequence

Tags: quickblox

I cannot understand somethings about the push notification with quickblox
I have a chat (a webchat) in a webview in a Xamarin apps (i know isn't very clever approach)

i try to create a subscrition via javascript
but i cannot undestand the way for calculate 
uuid and client_identification_sequence

```js
            var params = {
                notification_channels: 'gcm',
                device: {
                    platform: 'android',
                    udid: '538a068a-d66a-44d4-86c8-18ffed7f20d8'
                },
                push_token: {
                    environment: 'development',
                    client_identification_sequence: ''
                }
            }; 
            QB.pushnotifications.subscriptions.create(params, function (err, res) {
                debugger;
                if (err) {
                    debugger;
                    // error
                } else {
                    debugger;
                    // success
                }
            });
```

i've tried to calculate the uuid with "Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo"
but what is the way  for client_identification_sequence?

should I take this value from the "apns" (for apple push notification) but where?
I have the same roblem with the xamarin project

```
   var d = await wbWrapper.SubscribeForPushNotificationAsync([pushtoken], CrossDeviceInfo.Current.GenerateAppId());
```

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

**uuid** - it's your device unique identifier. It's actually can be anything that uniquely identify current particular device.

**client_identification_sequence** - it's your push token. 
For Android - it's registration id (or registration token).
For iOS - it's device token